# The "BeginSession" method has not been called or it did not succeed - QBFC SDK12 and ASP.NET WebSite

Tags: c#, asp.net, quickbooks, qbfc

I have the following code

```
    QBSessionManager sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();
    RequestProcessor2Class requestProcessor = new RequestProcessor2Class();

    try
    {
        IMsgSetRequest msgSetRequest = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0);
        msgSetRequest.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeStop;

        // Query all the customers
        ICustomerQuery customerQuery = msgSetRequest.AppendCustomerQueryRq();
        customerQuery.ORCustomerListQuery.CustomerListFilter.ORNameFilter.NameFilter.MatchCriterion.SetValue(ENMatchCriterion.mcContains);
        customerQuery.ORCustomerListQuery.CustomerListFilter.ORNameFilter.NameFilter.Name.SetValue(customerName);


        inputRequestXML = msgSetRequest.ToXMLString();


         requestProcessor.OpenConnection("QBWebSite", "QuickBooks");
        ticket = requestProcessor.BeginSession("$Path\\sample_consulting business.qbw",QBFileMode.qbFileOpenDoNotCare);

        response = requestProcessor.ProcessRequest(ticket, inputRequestXML);
        responseTextbox.Text = response;
```

While postback of the page it throws the "The "BeginSession" method has not been called or it did not succeed" and the COMException is 
"[COMException (0x8004040c): The "BeginSession" method has not been called or it did not succeed.]"

What am I doing wrong.  Please help

I am using the quickbooks 14 enterprise version with .NET 4.0 framework.  I made sure that the 32 bit flag is set to true in IIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, you need to call BeginSession on the SessionManager before you create your request. This is the connection code that I use as a template:

```
          

QBSessionManager SessionManager = null;

        try
        {
            SessionManager = new QBSessionManager();
            SessionManager.OpenConnection2("AppID", "AppName", ENConnectionType.ctLocalQBD);
            SessionManager.BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);
            IMsgSetRequest MsgRequest = SessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0);
            MsgRequest.ClearRequests();
            MsgRequest.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeStop;

            // Create request here ///////////////////////////////////////////                               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log or display the error
        }
        finally
        {
            if (SessionManager != null)
            {
                SessionManager.EndSession();
                SessionManager.CloseConnection();
                SessionManager = null;
            }
        }
```